# Link the width of a div to a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, width

I was trying to use this code:

```
$("#a").click(function(event) {

    var n = $("#uno").innerWidth();
    var a = $("#due").innerWidth();

    if (n = a) {
        $("#uno").css('width', '1000px');
    } else {
        $("#uno").css('width', '400px')
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

So that when i click on that link, if the width of the div #uno matches the width of the other div, I get it to a width of 1000px, and if not, it returns to a width of 400px.
This is the idea, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: you're not comparing but assigning: `if (n = a) {`, use `==` or `===` to compare...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use one `=` it's an assigment and not a comparision. Try to use `==` or `===` to compare.

```
if (n == a) {
    $("#uno").css('width', '1000px');
} else {
    $("#uno").css('width', '400px')
}
```